# Should we integrate SpringMVC(Thymeleaf, Jsp) with Js frameworks (Reactjs, AngularJs,..)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm new to Js frameworks like Reactjs, AngularJs. 
And I'm tasked by my customers with the responsibility of researching to integrate Thymeleaf with one of javascript framework to **handle common components** (commonality and componentization task) in my project. 
But i'm wondering whether it's necessary to use a js framework along with SpringMVC and should we combine these technologies in java web application?
Thanks alot. I have searched for result for hours but no appropriate one found!

Answer (score 0):

please refer blow 2 link,

https://github.com/noveogroup-amorgunov/spring-mvc-react

https://medium.com/@pietroghezzi/spring-and-react-js-the-easy-way-5abe8a529058

I develop differently these examples, first I develop frontend project and build. after creating an MVC project and moved my static build into the static folder. then build java project got a working project.

Comment: it's not really my expected answer. Please focus on the topic: Is it necessary to use a js framework along with SpringMVC and should we combine these technologies in java web application?
Even though, I still cannot up-vote your comment due to my low reputation :)

Comment: you find answer here https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html